# Receiving 530 login incorrect error for all user accounts other than my own: vsftpd Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, user-accounts, vsftpd

I just setup a vsftpd server.  I have a few accounts for family and friends (actual useradd accounts) and mounted a shared directory in their home folder.  However, I seem to be the only one with ftp access.  This is what comes up if I try to ftp in with 'someotheruser':

```
$ ftp somewhere.net
Connected to somewhere.net.
220 (vsFTPd 2.3.5)
Name (somewhere.net:myusername): someotheruser
...
530 Login incorrect.
```

I find this weird because I did not specify my username (myusername) in the ftp command as per the prompt in line 4.

.conf is as follows:

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
```

FYI: I've tried changing pam_service_name to ftp.  This just causes a different error:

```
500 OOPS: cannot change directory:/home/someotheruser
```